# Move search box into top menu - Opencart

Tags: opencart, menubar, search-box

I was trying to move the search box into the top menu bar and the result was: fatal error :(

I mean: top menu with categories and at the end of them, the search box.

So, would somebody help me step by step how to do that without dying in the attempt?

Comment: Please, post here what have You tried and the whole error message. I do not understand why moving around few pieces of HTML would end in fatal error.

Comment: Shadyyx, fatal errar was just my own comment about the result. I tried to follow these steps: http://www.ubuntudog.com/?article=62 and the result was a disaster.

Comment: Well, the search is located in the header, where the menu normally resides as well. Therefore the only thing You normally need is to change a few lines in `header.tpl` to modify the HTML markup accordingly. The article You are pointing to is about moving the search module away from header and adding it to a completely different module container. **Where is Your *menubar* located?** In the `header.tpl` or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes Shadyyx, it is in the header.tpl, also the menu.

Comment: Then forget about the article You have read. All You need is to open the `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl`, cut off the code for search box and paste it into the div, where the menu resides. Play with CSS until it meets Your needs. Done.

Comment: You are great! I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Shadyyx, it worked as a charm. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome... I'll write that down into the answer so that You can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the menu bar (main navigation) and search box are both located in `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl` You do not need to follow any articles regarding how to display and make work the search box in different module positions (content_top, column_left, etc).

All You need to do is to open up the mentioned template file in a text editor (or Your IDE) and cut off the code for search box and paste it into the div, where the menu resides. Play with CSS until it meets Your needs. Done.